# C preprocessor macro - creating code from configuration table

Tags: configuration, macros, c-preprocessor

I (have to) use C preprocessor to create code from some kind of configuration table. The goal is that the configuration can be seen at one glance, each setting (=array name and size) is only defined once, and it should be easy to add / remove config items.

dumbed down, I need something like this:

```
config table
 no | size | buffer_name
  0    300    Foo_0
  1    280    Bar_1
```

shall create code like this:

```
// first create the buffers
int Foo_0[300]
int Bar_1[280]

// then create a configuration the software will use.

#define NO_OF_ITEMS 2

// this array defines the sizes
const int bufferSizes[NO_OF_ITEMS] = {300, 280}

// this array defines the pointers to the buffers
const int* bufferPointers[NO_OF_ITEMS] = {Foo_0, Bar_1}
```

limitations:
The buffers (Foo_0 and Bar_1) need to have separate arrays and cannot be one big array - they have to be allocated into several memory areas.

I tried to create a "config macro" and a "generator macro" but had no idea how to "store and recall" the config items since a macro cannot create a second macro.

```
CONFIG_CREATE (0, 300, Foo_0)
CONFIG_CREATE (1, 280, Bar_1)

CONFIG_GENERATE_BUFFER (0)
CONFIG_GENERATE_BUFFER (1)
// will create the buffers based on values above)

CONFIG_GENERATE_SIZES
// generates const int bufferSizes[NO_OF_ITEMS] = {300, 280}

CONFIG_GENERATE_POINTERS
// generates const int* bufferPointers[NO_OF_ITEMS] = {Foo_0, Bar_1}
```

All other ways have redundant info (like: the size has to be correct in the buffer definition and the bufferSizes array, and especially if the number of config entries gets big, there is big room for mistakes.

I also tried the "classical" configuration table via a typedef like:

```
const configItems staticBufferConfiguration[] =
[0] = {300, Foo_0}
[1] = {280, Bar_1}
}
```

The problem is, also here I have to create the buffers seperately, and they need to have the same size like in the config table.
I cannot use the size from the table to create the buffers with the correct length.
Using Macros for the lengths is not a clean solution as well, since I still have to manually add the correct macros into the correct table. Source for errors if the config gets more complex and has more entries:

```
int Foo_0[FOO_0_LENGTH];
int Bar_1[BAR_1_LENGTH];
int BarXE_2[BARXE_2_LENGTH];
int BarXE_3[BARXE_3_LENGTH];
int BarXE_4[BARXE_4_LENGTH];


const configItems staticBufferConfiguration[] =
[0] = {FOO_0_LENGTH, Foo_0}
[1] = {BAR_1_LENGTH, Bar_1}
[2] = {BARXE_2_LENGTH, BarXE_2}
[2] = {BARXE_2_LENGTH, BarXE_3}
[3] = {BARXE_4_LENGTH, BarXE_4}
// can you spot the copy/paste mistake??
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [x-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) concept:

```
#define TBL(f) \
    /*size name*/ \
    f(300, Foo_0) \
    f(200, Bar_1) \
    f(100, Baz_2) \
    // ...

#define F1(size,name) int name[size];
TBL(F1)

#define F2(size,name) size, 
const int bufferSize[] = { TBL(F2) };

#define F3(size,name) name, 
const int* bufferPointers[] = { TBL(F3) };
```

this will generate expand to the following code:

```
int Foo_0[300]; int Bar_1[200]; int Baz_2[100];
const int bufferSize[] = { 300, 200, 100, };
const int* bufferPointers[] = { Foo_0, Bar_1, Baz_2, };
```

The idea should be pretty self explanatory.

You can now get the `NO_OF_ITEMS` using `sizeof`:

```
#define NO_OF_ITEMS (sizeof bufferSize / sizeof *bufferSize)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the powerful x-macros. This is perfect and works (almost) like a charm
One question I came across while trying out: I have some config items which are supposed to stay empty, like:
`#define TBL(f) \`
`    /*size name*/ \`
`    f(300, Foo_0) \`
`    f(0, NULL_PTR) \`
`    f(100, Baz_2) \`

result should be for 2nd entry:
no definiton of the int[] array
and bufferPointers should look like this:
`const int* bufferPointers[] = { Foo_0, NULL_PTR, Baz_2, };`

Is there any way to cover this use case with x-macros? Because here I cannot give a condition, right?

Comment: @arnschi it's possible to create a condition in the preprocessor, here is an easy solution: https://godbolt.org/z/bd66zf4c3

Comment: Edit: I meant to use F1_NULL_PTR##name instead of F1_##name##name, but both should work